# Arrayformula with multiple VLOOKUP conditions doesnt work correctly

Tags: google-sheets

I need a list with all revenues matching multiple conditions (country abbr & year/month with wildcard) using vlookup and an arrayformula like this one:

```
=SVERWEIS(1;{ARRAYFORMULA((Tabellenblatt2!A:A=A5&"*")*(Tabellenblatt2!B:B=A1));Tabellenblatt2!C:C};1;FALSCH)
```

This doesnt work. I dont know why. Here is the google sheet document where I test it:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ilCeOLSx815OalPkYQyQcFROnWaz_5X3u0-C4N8Bbs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this within your sheet.

**Also cell A2 here is just marked month number value(1) while in your sheet the input is -01-**

Using VLOOKUP

```
=VLOOKUP(EOMONTH(DATE(A3;A2;1);0)&A1;{INDEX(QUERY({EOMONTH(Tabellenblatt2!A2:A;0)&Tabellenblatt2!B2:B\Tabellenblatt2!C2:C};"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) Where Col2 IS NOT NULL GROUP by Col1 LABEL Sum(Col2) ''"))};2;)
```

[image]

the same came be done via FILTER()

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(Tabellenblatt2!C:C;EOMONTH(Tabellenblatt2!A:A;0)=EOMONTH(DATE(A3;A2;1);0);Tabellenblatt2!B:B=A1)))
```

IF you just need the values list then:

```
=FILTER(Tabellenblatt2!C:C;EOMONTH(Tabellenblatt2!A:A;0)=EOMONTH(DATE(A3;A2;1);0);Tabellenblatt2!B:B=A1)
```

[image]